# YouTubePlayerFragment not working in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I am working on an app where most work is done using Fragments. In one fragment I have to show a recycle view containing the Youtube Player. But Youtube Player only appear in first row of recycle view. I have this code for recycleView Adapter.

```
 public static class VideoViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
       public FrameLayout ViewVideo;
     ViewVideo = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MainVideo);
    }
```

on Bind method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, final int position) {  
youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();   
        FragmentTransaction transaction = VideoPage.getChildFragment().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(holder.ViewVideo.getId(), youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("****************************", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VideoAvaliable[position]);
//                    youTubePlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                String errorMessage = youTubeInitializationResult.toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

in my layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'FrameLayout' use

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and try

Comment: not working application crashing after i replace frame layout with fragment

Comment: @imrohit 
I'm using Fragment the video is playing but after a millisecond it stops. Do you have any ideas?
And I put <fragment> inside <ConstraitLayout>  otherwise it crashes